# Spliting .mat file

Tags: python, matlab

Hi I'm having a problem splitting .mat file into separated values

Here is how I load files

```
import scipy.io 

szum_1 = scipy.io.loadmat('szum_1.mat')['szum_1']
szum_2 = scipy.io.loadmat('szum_2.mat')['szum_2']
```

And output:

```
[ 3.29420368  2.2221562   1.9350699   1.23158597  2.57708046  1.94689757 etc.]
```

So as you can see it's a whole bunch of values packed into one cell

I've tried using `np.char.split(szum_1[0], sep=' ')` but I got an error
'string operation on non-string array' and I have no other idea on how to split these numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` works only for strings, so you should convert the numbers into strings using `str()`

```
import scipy.io 
szum_1 = str(scipy.io.loadmat('szum_1.mat')['szum_1'])
szum_2 = str(scipy.io.loadmat('szum_2.mat')['szum_2'])
```